# Determine if a number is a whole number?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, division

I'm trying to make a program that will divide a number by 2 only if that number is divisible by 2. I made it so that if the result of the number divided by 2 is a float, then divide it by two, like this:

```
int p;
printf("Percentage please: ");
scanf("%d", &p);
while (((p/2) != // a floating point value)
{
    p = p/2;
}
```

But the problem is that I'm not sure if there is a function in the C standard libraries like `isint()` or `iswholenumber()`. Is there any function or any way I could implement something similar?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the modulo operation, that returns the rest of the division, so:

```
if( n % 2 == 1) // the number is not divisible by 2
if( n % 2 == 0) // divisible by 2
```

Comment: Is modulo by a negative number defined in C?

Comment: Yep, it's still the remaining on the division, -5 % 2 = -1

Comment: __C 2011 Section 6.5.5 Paragraph 6:__  If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`; otherwise, the behavior of both `a/b` and `a%b` is undefined.

Comment: That's why it's not the modulo operator, but the remainder operator.

Comment: `if( n % 2 == 0)` is correct, `if( n % 2 == 1)` is wrong, it should be `if( n % 2 != 0)` to work for negative `n`.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide two `int`s the result is always an `int` (edit: truncated):

```
1/2 --> 0
2/2 --> 1
3/2 --> 1
```

So the logic `p/2 is not a float` does not make sense. Instead, as others have suggested, you want to use the modulo operator which returns the remainder of the division:

```
if( n % 2 ) // not divisible by 2
{
}
else // divisible by 2
{
}
```

Note: Since all integers that do not evaluate to 0 are equivalent to `true` you do not need to check `n % 2 != 0`.

Comment: It's not rounded down, it's truncated (which rounds negative numbers upwards).

Comment: For example, `-3/2` rounds towards zero with a value of `-1`, not `-2`.

Comment: updated. forgot about negatives.

Answer (score -2):

you could ask the user for a string, then use int.TryParse

```
int x;
if (int.TryParse(inputString, out x))
{
    // input is an integer.
}
```

Comment: int.TryParse isn't C, and this question is tagged C